# Is it possible for Google workspace admin to restrict some/all users of a Google Workspace account from creating script files?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible for Google workspace admin to restrict some/all users of a Google Workspace account from creating script files.

Comment: Upon checking, Apps Script doesn't have its own service in the Google Workspace Admin Console that can be disabled to a certain org unit or group. Alternatively, you can check https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227#trustorlimit (however, this is a domain wide setup), https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289#url_blocklist (this will only work if users are using chrome OS/chrome browser with domain account synced on the device/browser) Or you can reach out to Google Workspace at https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213 for better advise/options.

Answer (score 0):

**AppScript** does not have an specific control to turn off the services for users within an specific organizational unit.

However, there is a workaround you could try in the **Google Workspace Admin console**, you could block access to the URL: https://script.google.com/.

To do so, in the **Admin console** at [Admin console](https://admin.google.com), go to the **Devices** menu, select **Chrome**.

In **Settings** select **User & browsers**, there press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search: **URL Blocking**.

Add the URLs you wish to block, for instance: https://script.google.com/ and click **Save**.

I hope that you find this solution helpful, please check the help center article for further reference: [Allow or block access to websites](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419).